# Which assets are best suited for a Roth IRA?

Tags: united-states, ira, roth-ira, asset-allocation

What are the most suitable assets types to own within a Roth IRA vs. a taxable account?

Generally, Roth IRAs are best suited for assets that a) generate a high return over a long holding period and b) are taxed at a comparably high rate. I'm looking for a list of specific assets, and this is what I've come up so far:

**Most Suitable:**

- Domestic REITs
- Domestic stocks with high dividend yield (if the tax-favored status of qualified dividends disappears)

**Not Suitable:**

- Treasuries/municipal bonds
- Foreign REITs
- Foreign dividend-paying stocks

Any other asset types I should add?

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track to answering your own question.

I guess you might add collectibles to the Roth if you can because gains on those are typically taxed at a higher rate.

Just remember that the rules on Roths can change at any time.  The rules now might be quite different from the rules when you want to withdraw.

Comment: According to http://www.irs.gov/publications/p590/ch01.html#en_US_2010_publink1000230870, buying collectibles may be considered a Prohibited Transaction, which results in the Roth IRA being liquidated and a 10% penalty assessed; there are limited exceptions for certain types of coins and bullion